# How to downgrade or uninstall Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 using Wubi. My internet driver is not supporting this version, so either I can downgrade to 8.10 or uninstall it and re-install the 8.10 version.

Please let me know how to do both of these things.

Comment: What is your network card? (Assuming that is 'internet driver'.) Maybe we can help with that. Ubuntu.com has great installation walkthroughs. You can also try the [Unix forum](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for driver support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wubi to [uninstall](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation) Ubuntu 10.10